# Metronome for the whole show with automatic midi synth switching. What's a good setup?

Tags: midi, live

My band wants to improve our live shows and have a metronome set up for the whole setlist. We want the keyboard to switch sounds automatically on specific bars. The tempo switches even mid-songs, so we'd have to have it programmed in Mainstage / Logic / other software.

Until now we used Mainstage for the keys (they were software synths from Mainstage). We want to keep that setup. We may want other backing audio tracks to play also during songs anyways.

What is the best way to have a backing track with midi signals that would switch keyboard patches in Mainstage automatically?

Can it be set up in Mainstage alone?
If so, can we use the midi markers to switch guitar effects too? (for effects that are capable recieving midi signals of course).

Thank you for your help!